# PhP login redirect stops working after applying CSS and JS to the code

Tags: javascript, php, http-redirect, login-script

I am trying to write a simple login code. The problem is that the code works and redirects to dashboard.php without any css and js files.
But as soon as include my header file,consisting of css and js, it stops working and gets stuck on auth_check.php.
Here is my code.

**main index file ( index.php) - containing the login form**

```
 <?php include('header.php');?>
 <?php

 $message = $_GET['message'];
 if($message == 1) {
    echo '
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
           Invalid username or password.</br> &times;</button>

    </div>
    ';

    }   
     if($message == 2) {
    echo '
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
             You have successfully logged out! </br> &times;</button>

    </div>
    ';

    }
         ?>



         <div data-role="content">

     <div id="loginform" > //Login form code

      <form action="auth_check.php" method="post"> // form action="auth_check.php"
   <div id="usernameDiv" data-role="field-contain">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div id="passwordDiv" data-role="field-contain">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div id="loginbuttonDiv" data-role="field-contain">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="loginbutton"></button>
 </div>

 </form>
 </div> 

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

**Authorisation check (auth_check.php) (here the header(location:) doesnt work after applying js in index.php :(**

```
  <?php
  include('config.php');
 session_start();

 include 'PasswordHash.php';

 $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);

 if (!empty($_POST))
 { 
   $username = $sql->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);


   $query = "SELECT id, password, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) AS salt
          FROM users
          WHERE username = '{$username}'";
  $user = $sql->query($query)->fetch_object();
    if ($user && $user->password == $hasher->CheckPassword($_POST['password'],  
        $user->password))
 {   

    session_register("username"); // session checker for pages
    $_SESSION['username']= $username; // storing username in session
    header("location: dashboard.php");
    exit;

  }
 else
  { 
     header("location: index.php?message=1");
     exit;
  }
}


?>
```

**here is the file header.php which is causing the problem.**

```
   <?php
  include('config.php');

   ?>
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-
   1.4.2.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>


  <head>
```

Comment: Remove any code you added until it works again. Then you'll know where your problem is.

Comment: How about posting `header.php` if you're so sure that it's causing the problem? ;-)

Comment: It is causing the problem because as soon as iremove it, the code works fine. Ihave had this problem in many other projects too. If I apply a different CSS and JS file to this code.It works. Only for my CSS and Js it doesnt.

Comment: Show us how you're applying the CSS/JS, with code examples.

Comment: Ihave posted the header.php code too.

Comment: You're displaying HTML (by including header.php), before calling the `header()` function. This is the problem.

Comment: And you should use `include_once`…

Comment: but I am including the header file in index.php whereas my redirection is performed in auth_check.php ( where there is no html before the header() ).?